# iOS 9 Beta 3 Can't Trust Enterprise Developer Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I updated to `iOS 9 Beta 3` today, and I need to test an IPA file on my phone.

I put it on, and it says I need to trust the developer first before I can open the app. I went to `Settings > General > Profiles`, and the option to do so is not present like it was in `iOS Beta 2`. Anyone else have this problem and a solution?

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar issue and I just resolved it. Below are the steps I took:

1. Open up Xcode 7 Beta 3
2. Open the Devices Window under the Window menu item (CMD+SHIFT+2)
3. Under Devices on the upper left select your device that you cannot run the app on
4. Right Click on your device and and select Show Provisioning Profiles
5. Select each provisioning profile on the phone and click the [-] to delete all of them.
6. Now try installing the app via Xcode, if you keep the Show Provisioning Profiles window open you will see it install the ones for your app.

That did the trick for me. I could not trust the app since it was not in the profiles and this got it to launch just fine now. Best of luck!

Comment: @Polar What to do when device is at remote location. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Rahul My assumed limitation with the remote location is that they do not have access to Xcode 7 beta X. Meaning they cannot delete the provisioning profiles. If thats the scenario I think you could just reset the device completely wiping all data on it, then set it up as a brand new iPhone. If you don't restore it then there should be no provisioning profiles on it after a full wipe which seems to be the key to resolving this issue. Not a great solution but thats my best idea in that situation.

Comment: Thanks @Polar.. Yes at remote location they don't have Xcode, actually i create ipa file with distribution profile and share with them and it work well with other devices but have problem with iOS 9 beta devices. And yes i don't think so they will restore their device for it. And in under Settings - General - Profiles there is not profile too delete other than iOS 9 beta profile.

Comment: Just a question,if i create ipa with Xcode 7 beta and share..will it be work..? because now i'm creating ipa file with Xcode 6.4.

Comment: @Rahul, how are those in the remote location without Xcode installing the .ipa you are making with your distribution profile?

I ask because from my experience you for example cannot install an .ipa from Xcode 6 onto a device running iOS 9. This limitation can be overcome by using iTunes to add the .ipa to the device but you need to usually be on the latest iTunes. 

You could also be using an OTA install method which could be failing for a completely different reason.

Comment: @RahulShirphule I'm not following the question about Xcode 7 beta and sharing or about creating the ipa with Xcode 6.4. Are you using Xcode 6 or 7 to create the ipa file?   

My recommendation is to use Xcode 7 if you are trying to install and use an iOS 9 device.

Comment: Thanks @Polar.Currently I'm using Xcode 6. And yes on remote location they are using iTunes to install .ipa file. I'll create .ipa  by the Xcode 7 and check will it work or not..? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by setting up Testflight internal testing through iTunes Connect. I can test my apps now.