# No Profiles tab in general settings when using iOS 9 beta 3+

Tags: ios, xcode7, ios9

When I try to run my app on `iOS 9 beta 3`, as well as `beta 4 & 5`, I get an error saying `Untrusted Enterprise Developer`

> **Untrusted Enterprise Developer**
>
> "iPhone Developer: name (id)" has not yet been trusted on this iPhone. Until this developer has been trusted, their enterprise apps will not be available for use.

In previous betas, the way to get rid of the message was to go to `General > Profiles` in the Settings app and trust the developer, but this is not present in beta 3, 4, or 5.

I've tried searching for `Profiles` in the settings app, and a tab named `Profiles & Device Management` shows up under general. Yet, when I tap on it, I am just brought to the top of the General tab, and `Profiles & Device Management` does not show up either.

I have all of the correct provisioning profiles on the device, and they are all valid.

Is this a bug in iOS 9 beta 3+, or is there some other way to trust the developer?

Comment: Have the same issue here. Was not aware of the search feature but can replicate the same problem you are experiencing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 9 Beta 3 Can't Trust Enterprise Developer Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306389/ios-9-beta-3-cant-trust-enterprise-developer-apps)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is nearly the same as provided by luthelis works in a little other way. You do not have to re-download the provisioning profiles from the developer center. You're going to do it like this:

1. Open your Xcode Beta 7
2. Click on `Window` -> `Devices` or use shortcut (`CMD+SHIFT+2`)
3. From the overview, select the device which is not able to run the application.
4. Right Click on your device and and select `Show Provisioning Profiles`
5. Select profile by profile and delte them by clicking the `-` button
6. Now try installing the app via Xcode, if you keep the Show Provisioning Profiles window open you will see it install the ones for your app.

as Polar Bear said over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31355561/3671726

Comment: The issue isn't with the provisioning profiles. (Read the comments on the other answer)

Comment: of course it has sth do to with that - or why does that fix the problem? :/

Comment: The only reason I manually installed the profiles was because I didn't trust a code to do it for me at this point. I figured a manual install would be more reliable.

Comment: Also, this answer is exactly copied from that link. You should at least rewrite it in your own words

Comment: Jojodmo do you understand where the problem is here or do you just want to give some input? There is **NO BUTTON** and **NO OPTION** to trust the developer anywhere on the iPhone! This is the only way how it'll work till there is a fix.

Comment: hell man what are you talking about - of course you're not able to run an application without any profile. If you delete such an application, do it like i told in my answer and of course you're able to run it again.

Comment: You commented on the other answer saying that you experienced the same thing described in the question after you deleted a development version of the app. What changed?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me running iOS 9 Beta 4 and Xcode 7 Beta 4.

Go to `Window -> Devices` or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> while the device is plugged in. In the bottom left corner under Devices there is a gear, click it and then click "Show Provisioning Profiles...".

Delete all profiles and re-download them from the Apple Developer Center,  then add the newly downloaded profiles to that window and it will push them to the device automatically.

The next time I built on the device it worked. Good luck to all.

Comment: I still get the **Untrusted Developer** message. The problem doesn't seem to be with the provisioning profiles, but trusting the developer. Something I learned is to ***NOT DELETE*** the development version of the app after you upgrade to iOS 9 beta 3+, because you will not be able to trust the developer again

Comment: I deleted all of them, app and profiles, and installed the profiles through Xcode manually. After that I installed the app through Xcode and it worked.

Comment: Read the comment above - that may have worked for you, but it doesn't work in this case because the issue isn't with the profiles.

Comment: Hell man... realy? We just deleted one application and are not able to reinstall it - with exactly the same problem like it is described here. Apple ... you must be kidding. ._. Since when should we wait now? Till september?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to run an App with a Developer Profile.
I got this fixed by creating a new Developer Profile with my developer account.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the question states that *"I have all of the correct provisioning profiles on the device, and they are all valid."* - I've already tried this and got the same result. The issue is with *trusting* the developer on the device